# using awk with parallel

Tags: bash, awk, gnu-parallel

I have about 3,000 files that are each 300MB, and I'd like to search them for a series of substrings as quickly as possible with my 16 core server.

This is what I tried but it doesnt seem to parallelize searching the files.

```
sudo find /mnt2/preprocessed/preprocessed/mo* | sudo xargs awk '/substring/ {c++} END {print c}' | paste -sd+ | bc
```

It's pasted together from different how-to's, I don't fully understand it. Do you have any suggestions for how I can split up the file processing?

Comment: You're likely I/O, not CPU-bound.

Comment: It's a high-I/O instance (hi1.4xlarge ec2), but you're probably right. I still want to know how to use GNU parallel in this context but haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. See whether you have the `parallel` program on your system.  (It may come from GNU.) 
   If you do, figure out how to use it. Otherwise,
2. Run your `find` with output to a file.  Using a text editor, or possibly a script using tools like `head`, split that file into 16 fragment files with (approximately) equal numbers of lines (i.e., referencing equal numbers of found files).  Then start 16 `awk … | paste … | bc` pipelines; one for each fragment file.  (And add the 16 results.)

I’m wondering why you’re using `awk` to count occurrences of a string when `grep -c` is specifically designed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

GNU parallel is pretty compatible with xargs, in your case it can replace it. If you are only counting occurrences of `substring` use `grep -c` as *Scott* suggests:

```
sudo find /mnt2/preprocessed/preprocessed/mo* | 
  sudo parallel grep -c source | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Note that some versions of GNU/Linux install GNU parallel in "Tollef's parallel" compatible mode. You can change that by adding `--gnu` to the command line arguments to parallel. To make the change permanent add `--gnu` to `~/.parallel/config`.

Comment: Grep turns out to be much slower than awk for some reason, which is why I went with awk.

Comment: This didn't work for me-- it doesn't process anything when I just use parallel in place of xargs.

Comment: post the output of 'parallel --version'

Comment: @kelorek: awk faster than grep? what versions of grep and awk are you using? In my tests counting occurrences in a 200M file `awk` takes 3.7s, `grep -c` takes 1.2s and `grep -Fc` takes 0.005s.